# Using StandardScaler to scale arrays with different shapes using spesific features

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn, normalization

I have a dataset with the following shapes:

X = (samples, 4)

y = (samples,)

I am using StandardScaler from sckikit-learn to normalize the data of X

I want to scale the y dataset with the same features used in one of the four columns of the X dataset, e.g scale all the values of y similarly to the second column of X.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose column in X you want to scale y based on that, is named 'A'.
You can do it as following :

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
scaler = StandardScaler()
scaler.fit(X['A'])
y = scaler.tansform(y)
```

Comment: Thank you, that would work. I would have to create two scales then if I would like to reuse the scale later, right?

Comment: You can create a scaler then fit it on a data and reuse it anywhere.